# Merging multiple date frames with different rows and also columns

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

[How my df looks like after joinging df1 and df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU03c.png)
I have multiple large data sets i wish to combine/merge.
Thank you for anwering. I did succeed by joining some of the dfs by full_join function. The problem now is that some of the data is missing when joining dfs., when i know that both df1 and df2 has data for columns with the same name:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wso6r.png)

I'm a bit out of depth here, hope you can help.

Comment: this is the error i often get through the different function i'v tried: Show in New Window
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
Show in New Window
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `1$Glu` <character> and `2$Glu` <double>.

Comment: Could you please update the question to have the example data as plain text?

Comment: Sounds like your `Glu` column is `character` class in one data frame and `numeric` (double) class in the other. You'll need to convert one of them to match the other before you `bind_rows()`.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want without any sample data or desired output. When you say *"the rows are different under sample description / group and needs to be added to one data frame"* it sounds like you want `bind_rows()`, but when you say *"here is "just" extra columns with the values connected to the sample description/group"* it sounds like you might want `merge`. These functions do different things, but without sample input and desired output I cannot tell which one you want. Please add sample data to the question.

Comment: The easiest way to add sample data is often `dput()`. `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` will make copy/pasteable R code to create the first 5 rows of `your_data`. Please share a small subset of each input and also the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: Thank you for anwering. I did succeed by joining some of the dfs by full_join function.

Comment: thank you for you answer, i did manage to change character, hvorever i found other challanges. I've asked a new question, which is better formulated as im new to R (
Missing data points after full_join())